# Php save post headers to file to view later

Tags: php, header

I am trying to view all of the pages headers and save them to file

```
file_put_contents("/var/www/rnli.hutber.com/controllers/api/location/post.json", json_encode($_POST));
```

This only outputs this however:

```
[]
```

But using another serivce I know there is a full post

```
Time: Tue, 07 Apr 15 09:36:37 -0700
Source ip: 77.103.1.179

Headers (Some may be inserted by server)
REQUEST_URI = /post.php
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_METHOD = POST
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
REMOTE_PORT = 34686
REMOTE_ADDR = 77.103.1.179
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
HTTP_CONNECTION = close
HTTP_HOST = posttestserver.com
CONTENT_LENGTH = 201
CONTENT_TYPE = application/json
HTTP_ACCEPT = application/json
UNIQUE_ID = VSQHldBx6hIAABF0UacAAAAF
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT = 1428424597.7112
REQUEST_TIME = 1428424597

No Post Params.

== Begin post body ==
{"auth_token":"hutber","test":"ing","location":{"latitude":"51.61755157","longitude":"-0.13905254","accuracy":"29.0","speed":"0.0","bearing":"0.0","altitude":"115.0","recorded_at":"2015-04-07T16:36Z"}}
== End post body ==

Upload contains PUT data:
{"auth_token":"hutber","test":"ing","location":{"latitude":"51.61755157","longitude":"-0.13905254","accuracy":"29.0","speed":"0.0","bearing":"0.0","altitude":"115.0","recorded_at":"2015-04-07T16:36Z"}}
```

http://posttestserver.com/data/2015/04/07/09.36.371974424473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$data = array_merge(apache_request_headers(), $_POST, $_SERVER);
file_put_contents("/var/www/rnli.hutber.com/controllers/api/location/post.json", json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this code

```
$headers = array();
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 5) <> 'HTTP_') {
        continue;
    }
    $headers[$key] = ($value);
}

file_put_contents("/var/www/rnli.hutber.com/controllers/api/location/post.json", json_encode($headers));
```